Story where the main character is hired as a FORTH interpreter. We pull back and realise he is a computer program living in a circuit board
I read this story well over 30 years ago (probably over 40 years ago), and don't remember many specific details. However, I do recall the overall story, and would like to find it again.
The main character answers a want ad, and takes a bus or train trip to the new job. On his way there, the landscape appears to change. The imagery suggested a "microbe's-eye view" of a circuit board. The roads were gold, buildings were low, wide, and black with silver pillars, etc. The job that the character was to do was to act as a FORTH interpreter (although I don't recall whether the story explicitly called it out as such) with the procedures described matching the operation of a FORTH interpreter, "scaled" to the real world.
Eventually, the protagonist starts getting tired of the standard procedure which are repetitious and mindless, and starts taking shortcuts that intelligence would suggest. Naturally, this leads to disaster.
I don't recall whether it was in a book about FORTH or computers, or whether it was a general fiction. My impression is that it was novelette or novella length rather than short story (and definitely not a novel).

Sounds like something Rudy Rucker could write

@Andrew - Yeah, I suppose it does - but even the 30-year date would have been well before I discovered Rucker.

Ask, and it shall be given you; seek, and ye shall find; knock, and it shall be opened unto you. For every one that asketh receiveth; and he that seeketh findeth.

What does FORTH stand for? Mentioning that might be helpful.

@Nu'Daq FORTH is a (relatively old) computer programming language. Despite often being styled in all caps, it's not actually an acronym.

@Hearth "Relatively Early" rather than "Relatively Old". I wish I had been on microcomputers instead of the horribad BASIC (Microsoftian or otherwise). Wikipedia on FORTH. Via that page, the addy-rich BYTE magazine 1980-08 where there happens to be an addy saying something about BASIC Additional laughs

This is My life as a Forth Interpreter by K (A.K.A. Brian Hayes). It was published in the magazine Computer Language in April, 1986.

At one point he interrupted himself to say, "It is old joke about
America: The streets are paved with gold." When I looked out the
window, I saw what he meant. We were on a park way, which wound among
the factory buildings and occasionally even passed under them. I
counted 16 parallel lanes, separated from one another by narrow grass
median strips. And yes, the road ways did have a metallic gleam,
although the color was more coppery than golden. The building where
the taxi left me was one of the larger examples of the new industrial
architecture, with a 20-column colonnade front and back. Inside it
seemed bigger still. The entire space was filled with brightly painted
machinery

You can read it in full here.

This somehow reminds me of the cartoon series "ReBoot" which I saw a few times in the 1990s. It, too, takes place inside a computer, and had vivid graphics that looked like circuitry and chips. "In the inner computer world of Mainframe, a guardian program sprite and his friends defend the system from threats from viruses and the User." -- IMDb

Somehow I think the FORTH Interpreter Person would be a safer bet than Crowdstrike "guardian software" :) Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?

"You're the new interpreter?" she said. "I'm Ms. Dos."

@Wastrel Well that's literally the story of the good old Tron.
